# WP Query always limiting posts to 5

Tags: wordpress

I have no idea why my posts are being limited to 5 - checked the docs, tried using both an array of arguments and also the query string (below), always 5 results only! Any idea why this could be happening?

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$tag = get_query_var('tag');
$query->query("post_type=drinks&numberposts=-1&posts_per_page=-1&taxonomy=drink-types&term=$tag");
```

Comment: What version of WordPress are you trying this on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be pagination related (you are only seeing one "page" of results). Try setting `'nopaging' => true` and/or `'posts_per_page' => '-1'` and see if that clears it up for you.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks, hadn't noticed that variable.